# PHP-FPM - problems with the pre-start process

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm, php5, service

My webserver runs NGINX with PHP-FPM. After (I guess) an update, the service php5-fpm stopped working and refuses to restart/start - even after a reboot. As another webserver does the same updates and still works, updates may not be the cause.

```
> sudo service php5-fpm start
start: Job failed to start
> sudo service php5-fpm status
php5-fpm stop/waiting

> cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.13.0-48-generic (buildd@orlo) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015
```

The `/var/log/syslog` says

```
kernel: [  131.844584] init: Failed to spawn php5-fpm pre-start process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
```

And there is no relevant entry in `/var/log/php5-fpm.log`or any other file in `/var/log/`.

I'm afraid, I lack the background knowledge on pre-start processes. Therefore, I do not know where to start... Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What's the upstart job pre-start section content ? (`/etc/init/php5-fpm.conf`)

Comment: Ah! That was the hint, I needed: `/etc/init/php5-fpm.conf` refered to a file `/usr/lib/php5/php5-fpm-checkconf`that did not exist. And I was unable to reinstall `php5-fpm`... The reason was a modification in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` (no universe...) that apparently caused a removal of the PHP-FPM package. *plonk* -- and thanks a lot! Please post the hint as answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: I just did it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the upstart job pre-start section content in `/etc/init/php5-fpm.conf`.